# Display Total amount in the admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have searched, didn't find any answer. I want to get the total of inline `salesitem` in the admin template. I want the `quantity * price` of the item to be shown in the admin inline table as I add quantity.
Example:

**models.py**

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField()
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Sales(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    #Other fields

class SalesItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Stock)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

**admin.py**

```
class SalesItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = SalesItem

class SalesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin, ExportCsvMixin):
    exclude = ['admin', 'branch']
    inlines = [SalesItemInline]
```

It is a mini inventory system that I already deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display model functions and properties in inlines. For example:

```
class SalesItem(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.item.price * self.quantity
```

and then add it as part of `readonly_fields` (because it is a computed property):

```
class SalesItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    ...
    fields = ('item', 'quantity', 'total')
    readonly_fields = ('total',)
```